# Flex menuitem from menubar disable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a small issue related to enabling/disabling menuitems in Flex.

The question is that I can disable directly a menuItem but not it's sub-menuitems.

I have the following menu structure:

```
public var menuAgroApp:XMLList =
        <>
            <menuitem label="ADMIN">
                <menuitem label="Option 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 2"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 3"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 4"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="Prices">
                <menuitem label="Price 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Price 2"/>
                <menuitem label="Price 3"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="Orders">
                <menuitem label="Order 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Order 2"/>
            </menuitem>
        </>;
```

With this code I can disable the menu "ADMIN" but not any Option:

```
menuPrincipal.dataDescriptor.setEnabled( XML(modeloGlobal.modelo.menuAgroAppCollection.source[0]), false );
```

The question is that, how can i get access menuItems within the ADMIN menuItem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution and the [working example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/04_19_menuitem/):

In order to take control over a submenu item you need to navigate to it using XML expressions and then point to the first element of the List. It is so because your XML-expression delievers a XMLList in a common case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]public var menuAgroApp:XMLList =
            <>
            <menuitem label="ADMIN">
                <menuitem label="Option 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 2"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 3"/>
                <menuitem label="Option 4"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="Prices">
                <menuitem label="Price 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Price 2"/>
                <menuitem label="Price 3"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="Orders">
                <menuitem label="Order 1"/>
                <menuitem label="Order 2"/>
            </menuitem>
            </>;

        protected function onOnOffAdmin(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            myMenuBar.dataDescriptor.setEnabled(menuAgroApp[0], false);
        }

        protected function onOnOffAdminOption2(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            myMenuBar.dataDescriptor.setEnabled(menuAgroApp[0].menuitem.(@label == 'Option 2')[0], false);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="30" y="30">
    <mx:MenuBar id="myMenuBar" labelField="@label" dataProvider="{menuAgroApp}"/>
    <s:Spacer height="20"/>

    <s:Button label="Set Off Admin" click="onOnOffAdmin(event)" />
    <s:Button label="Set Off Admin/Option2" click="onOnOffAdminOption2(event)" />
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```